# Error while pivoting Data Frame

Tags: r, reshape

I have a Data frame with all variables  as factor type

```
col0         col1     col2       col3 ..  Col100 
2017-01-01     12       23         34  ..   10
2017-01-02     119       24         39  ..   12
```

I am trying to get output as below with `df1 <- melt(df)`

```
Variable   Val
date     2017-01-01
date     2017-01-02
col1      12
col1      119
col2      23
col2      24
.
.
Col100    12
```

Any dynamic way to get the above output?

Answer (score 2):

Just specify all columns as measure variables:

```
melt(df, measure.vars = 1:5)
```

which gives:

```
   variable      value
1      col0 2017-01-01
2      col0 2017-01-02
3      col1         12
4      col1        119
5      col2         23
6      col2         24
7      col3         34
8      col3         39
9    Col100         10
10   Col100         12
```

This works with the `melt`-functions from both `reshape2` as well as `data.table`.

---

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(col0 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("2017-01-01", "2017-01-02"), class = "factor"), 
                     col1 = c(12L, 119L), col2 = 23:24, col3 = c(34L, 39L), Col100 = c(10L, 12L)), 
                .Names = c("col0", "col1", "col2", "col3", "Col100"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We may need a sequence variable

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE), id.var = 'rn')[, -1]
#   variable      value
# 1:     col0 2017-01-01
# 2:     col0 2017-01-02
# 3:     col1         12
# 4:     col1        119
# 5:     col2         23
# 6:     col2         24
# 7:     col3         34
# 8:     col3         39
# --
# --
#201:   Col100         10
#202:   Col100         12
```

NOTE: By doing the `melt`, columns having different `class` will get mixed up in a single 'value' column which would be `character` or `factor` depending on the initial `class` of 'col0'

---

Or we can just use `gather`

```
library(tidyr)
gather(df1)
```